# How to create new draggable component when mouse clicked in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm new in ExtJS and also Javascript. 
I want to create a new component when clicked a certain component. But while mouseUp (mouse not released) created component must be draggable with mouse move. I wrote some code but of course this is not working. In this code I created dummy text inside "< p >" tag. When clicked this text, I want to create a copy of that and drag the created text and drop it anywhere in a page. How can I do that? Does anybody have an idea?

```
    var dummy_text_comp = Ext.getCmp('dummy_text');
    dummy_text_comp.on('click',handleDrag());
    function handleDrag (){
        var dummy_text_copy = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            autoEl : {
                html : 'This is dummy text',
                tag : 'h1'
            },
            draggable : true;
        });
        dummy_text_copy.originalXY = dummy_text_comp.getXY();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of ExtJs are you using? The 3 and 4 version have different way for creating of DD.

Here are some examples for  ExtJs 3.4.
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/#sample-14